# require all gems in Gemfile in non-Rails app?

Tags: rubygems, bundler

When we write `Rails` app it requires all the gems defined in `Gemfile` for us.

How to make a non-Rails app do this?

Answer (score 14):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require(:default)
```

The above requires the gems in particular groups, noting that gems outside of a named group are in the :default group

See here: https://bundler.io/v2.0/guides/groups.html